# Make a copy in python

Tags: python

Function below does make a copy of given data.

```py
def copyA(data):
    acopy = []
    for d in data:
        acopy.append(d)
    return acopy
```

But when I use it in an another function it does return anything. Can anybody tell me what's wrong and how can I fix it?

```py
def selection_sort(unsorted):
    result = list()
    acopy=[]
    for d in unsorted:
        acopy.append(d)
        return acopy
    while len(acopy) > 0:
        out = min(acopy)
        acopy.remove(out)
        result.append(out)
        return result
    print(result)
unsorted=[1,2,3,6,4,2,1,6,5]
selection_sort(unsorted)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to fix the indentation.  It's impossible to tell what code is supposed to be part of the function.

Comment: your `copyA` definitely *does* copy a list, although, it is totally pointless, because you can copy a list by using `mylist.copy()`, or `mylist[:]`, or even `list(mylist)`....

Comment: I am sorry but the requirement asked for it thats why I could not use copy().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `return` stops the function it is placed in as soon as it is encountered, hence `selection_sort` does not reach the `while` loop. If you delete `return acopy` it should work as expected